# Casting HTMLElement to HTMLAudioElement

Tags: typescript

I have this line of typescript:

```
var audio: HTMLAudioElement = document.getElementById("audioElement");
```

However, I get the build error:

```
Type HTMLElement is not assignable to type 'HTMLAudioElement'.
```

Is there a different way I should be retrieving the element as an HTMLAudioElement, or do I just cast it to HTMLAudioElement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The casting sutras for typescript looks like this:

```
const audio = document.getElementById("audioElement") as HTMLAudioElement;
```

And you can either specify the type on the audio variable if you want, but typescript will pick that up automatically for you.